# python sys.stdin.read() unwanted split

Tags: python, linux, stdin, geoip

i'm trying to make a script that i can pipe IP addresses to and have it return the geoip location. When I try this, it looks like its splitting each IP address by 1 character at a time and failing when trying to run iplookup()

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from geoip import geolite2
def iplookup(srcip):
    for ip in srcip:
            print(ip)
            try:
                    print(geolite2.lookup(ip))
            except:
                    print("oops")
                    pass


source = sys.stdin.read()
iplookup(source)
```

Echo a sample of data (That in the future i would like to come from tail -f fast.log) command to extract only the IP addresses

`[root@suricata py]# echo "05/20/2015-15:57:34.607470  [**] [1:2020702:2] ET DOS Bittorrent User-Agent inbound - possible DDOS [**] [Classification: Attempted Denial of Service] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 8.8.8.8:2039 -> 1.1.1.1:80" | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | python mygeoip.py`

```
8
oops
.
oops
8
oops
.
oops
8
oops
.
oops
8
oops
```

etc...

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` gives you **a string**, which you iterate over character by character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.stdin.read() gives you a string, if you have comma separated IP addresses, Do something like this

```
source = sys.stdin.read()
for ip in source.split(","):
    print(geolite2.lookup(ip))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This method works though. The confusion was that a string in python was a list of characters.

Comment: @dobbs a *sequence* of characters; Python lists are mutable, strings aren't.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `iplookup("stackoverflow.com")`, your python function is going to do exactly what you told it to do, which is to walk over the elements of the input array. Your `for` loop tells python to walk over the list.

A string in python is a list of characters.

So either don't do that (kill the loop), or call your function via `iplookup((source,))`, or `iplookup([source])`.

Comment: You'd actually need a comma after source in iplookup((source)). Python treats () applied to a single value as an evaluation of an expression. To make it a tuple, do iplookup((source,))

Comment: @Andrew - Fixed, thanks. `[source]` forces python to construct a list, while `(source)` gets flattened. Using `(source,)` doesn't get flattened, and I should know that; I've been bitten by that "feature."